# Is there a Sonar webservice API that lists all the libraries a project uses?

Tags: java, sonarqube

There is a webpage that shows this information, but the webservice API docs do not mention any apis for listing libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such webservice API available.
Could you please move to the user mailing-list to detail and discuss your needs? See http://www.sonarsource.org/get-support/